# Dismiss pushed view from within Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a Navigation Controller with a View Controller displaying a button. The button is linked to another View Controller using a push segue which automatically adds a top navigation bar with a back button. This all works fine. Pressing the back button slides off the 2nd view and returns to the 1st.

I have a button on the 2nd View Controller, that when pressed runs some code and a delegate call back to the 1st View Controller. Again this works fine.

Now I just need to dismiss the 2nd pushed View from code as if the back button was pressed.
I have tried using dismissModalViewCcontrollerAnimated and dismissViewControllerAnimated, however they both dismiss the whole Navigation Controller which removes view 2 and 1 (returning bak to my main menu).

Whats the correct way to slide off the view.

Comment: Can you post the code you used to test?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Obtain a reference to your UINavigationController and call

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

on it.

Comment: Thanks. That put me on the right path for a quick Google search.
This worked
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: That's still moving back two levels for me, not just dismissing the last-pushed view.

Answer (score 12):

In Swift it would be calling the method

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

If we use push segue, then use popViewController

```
@IBAction func backButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In swift you can also call:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

On Objective-C is

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

for a jump to the first `root` controller

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or is a possible move to the specific controller

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:(nonnull UIViewController *) animated:(BOOL)];
```

animation specific animation process of move the controller. If the animation is `false` the controller will appear without animations.
The `UIViewController` must be from one which is on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

If NavViewController is used with UIModalPresentationFullScreen then the below line will work

```
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```